# How to set a web page while clicking on a button ? with JavaFX

Tags: netbeans, webview, javafx

i'm trying to get an `URL` from `TextField` exapmle: `http://www.google.com` and i have a `WebView`that it will be visible by clicking on the "Enter key" but the problem is when i run the application it didn't show anything note that i'm using `FXML File`.This is the code i've traied:

```
@FXML
private void onpressed (ActionEvent ee) {
     text1.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
         public void handle(KeyEvent evt) {
       if (evt.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
       String az = text1.getText();
       //c.1
       if(text1.getText().equals("1")){
           web1.setVisible(true);
            String hh = text11.getText();
            Socket socket = new Socket();

    try {
        //open cursor
        text1.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        que.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        writ.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        ancpa.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web1.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web2.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web3.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web4.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web5.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web6.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web7.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web8.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web9.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        //do work
        WebEngine myWebEngine = web1.getEngine();
        myWebEngine.load("http://www.google.com");
        //close the window chooser
        Stage stage = new Stage();
          Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Choose.fxml"));
          Scene scene = new Scene(root);
         stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
              @Override public void handle(WindowEvent t) { } });
        //close cursor
        ancpa.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web1.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web2.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web3.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web4.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web5.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web6.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web7.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web8.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web9.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    }
   catch (IOException e){
       final  Stage stg = new Stage();           
        stg.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stg.initOwner(stg);
        stg.setTitle("Cannot connect to the internet /n Please Verify your connection internet");
        labelno.setText("Cannot connect to the internet...");
        //close chooser
        Stage stage = new Stage();
         stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
              @Override public void handle(WindowEvent t) { } });

       //set cursor
         ancpa.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web1.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web2.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web3.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web4.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web5.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web6.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web7.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web8.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web9.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
   } finally{
       try{ socket.close(); } catch (Exception e){ }
       }

          } 
         }
         }

 });

}
```

So please can any body explain for me where is the problem for this code and i'll be so thankful :)

Comment: Edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - ensure it is both minimal and executable so that it will replicate the issue when somebody runs it.

Comment: I have also noticed that all of your questions do not have accepted answers so if you are satisfied with the answer someone has posted right bellow the vote up and down arrow click on the check mark to accept  an answer

Comment: @APro Did I answer your question to your liking?

Comment: @sazzy4o now i'm trying your code and if the problem solved i'll put "accept this question" but anyway thank you for help me :)

Comment: @APro If it doesn't work post the error and ill try and fix it

Comment: @sazzyo okay! but currently i'm trying to fix this code and make it works if i find any error i'll send you

Comment: @APro I added a complete sample application that I hope you can modify for you needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure if you want 'if(text1.getText().equals("1")){' the if statement will only be true if someone types in the character "1" but how you set the web engine is by getting the text from the text field (text1) and getting the web engine to load it and it is good practice to put a .trim() at the end incase the user accidentally types in a space at the beginning of the end.
So your code should look something like this:

```
String urlString = text1.getText().trim();
WebEngine myWebEngine = web1.getEngine();
myWebEngine.load(urlString);
```

And you complet code should look something like this:

```
@FXML
private void onpressed (ActionEvent ee) {
     text1.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
         public void handle(KeyEvent evt) {
       if (evt.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
       String az = text1.getText();
           web1.setVisible(true);
            String hh = text11.getText();
            Socket socket = new Socket();

    try {
        //open cursor
        text1.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        que.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        writ.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        ancpa.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web1.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web2.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web3.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web4.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web5.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web6.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web7.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web8.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        web9.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        String urlString = text1.getText().trim();
        WebEngine myWebEngine = web1.getEngine();
        myWebEngine.load(urlString);    
        Stage stage = new Stage();
          Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Choose.fxml"));
          Scene scene = new Scene(root);
         stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
              @Override public void handle(WindowEvent t) { } });
        //close cursor
        ancpa.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web1.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web2.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web3.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web4.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web5.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web6.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web7.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web8.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web9.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    }
   catch (IOException e){
       final  Stage stg = new Stage();           
        stg.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stg.initOwner(stg);
        stg.setTitle("Cannot connect to the internet /n Please Verify your connection internet");
        labelno.setText("Cannot connect to the internet...");
        //close chooser
        Stage stage = new Stage();
         stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
              @Override public void handle(WindowEvent t) { } });

       //set cursor
         ancpa.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web1.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web2.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web3.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web4.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web5.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web6.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web7.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web8.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        web9.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
   } finally{
       try{ socket.close(); } catch (Exception e){ }
       }

          } 
         }
         }

 });

}
```

I hope this helps. If you have any questions just ask.

Comment: i found the problem this code it didn't work on my computer sorry :( i think the problem is in the "setOnKeyPressed" ithink it's "setOnKeyTyped" no?

Comment: @APro What errors do you get or do you not get any errors?

Comment: i'm really wanted "if(text1.getText().equals("1")){" beacause this KeyListener should be in the TextField and this TextField should contains "1" and then press enter to open the web page

Comment: if you want the to be anything other than the number "1" in your text field you might want to use .contains("1") instead of .equals("1") for example the if statement will return true if someone types in "http://www.1and1.ca/" but if you use .equals("1") it will return false also did my other answer the one from 5 hours ago answer your question? I think it is a better example

Comment: Yes thank you it helped me so mich really thank you for solving my error ;)

Comment: @APro Any time if there is any other code you are stuck on just comment

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example application that goes to the web page you typed in when you press enter in the text field:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {




@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

    final TextField text1 = new TextField();
    WebView web = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine= web.getEngine();
    text1.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.getCode().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("ENTER")) {
                           String urlString = text1.getText().trim();
                           webEngine.load(urlString);

    }
    }
    });
    pane.getChildren().addAll(web,text1);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch("application.Main");
}
}
```

You can try typing in https://www.google.com and it should take you there
If you exclude the http or https it should not work
Depending on your jre you may need to remove the @Override
I hope this helps